# Which Lego set do I have? mostly yellow and seems to be based off of construction

Tags: set-identification

The Lego set includes one minifigure with a blue cap, a red shirt, and blue pants. It also includes a window piece, some yellow connections, a black digger piece with the same connection and wheels. The set is mostly yellow and seems to be based off of construction. I tried to find it on other sites, but couldn't find anything. The set appears to be from the 2010s, and seems to be made for younger kids, but not quite Duplo.

Comment: A photo of the more distinctive pieces may prove useful here.

Answer (score 1):

Best match I can find fitting that description is set [4667 - Loadin’ Digger](https://brickset.com/sets/4667-1/Loadin-Digger) from 2004.

[image]

This set is from the 4 Juniors line, and features a non-traditional minifigure, larger than the iconic ones, from the Jack Stone line of figures.